# How to use prepared statements with Android sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, prepared-statement

so I am trying to understand how prepared statements are handled exactly? I have this code but I am unsure if it is using prepared statement or how to add prepared statements to it.

Code:

```
/*
     * Creating a word
     */
    public long createword(DatabaseWords word) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DICTIONARYID, word.get_dictionaryId());
        values.put(KEY_WORD1, word.get_word1());
        values.put(KEY_WORD2, word.get_word2());
        values.put(KEY_WORD3, word.get_word3());
        values.put(KEY_WORD4, word.get_word4());

        // insert row
        long word_id = db.insert(TABLE_WORDS, null, values);

        return word_id;

    }
```

How do I include prepared statements to A. make it go quicker, B. prevent attacks to the db

Comment: insertHelper is depreciated instead you should use transactions.

Comment: What is the question, really?

Comment: How do I include prepared statements to A. make it go quicker, B. prevent attacks to the db

Comment: @Nun Chai am I even using insertHelper?

Comment: I posted that comment in view (Vision) of your intended goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `insert()` uses prepared statements under the hood: `sqlite_prepare_v2()` to compile the SQL and then `sqlite3_bind_*()` to bind the arguments from `ContentValues`. This prevents the usual SQL injection attacks.

To use prepared statements for performance i.e. do the SQL compilation only once and reuse the same prepared statement for multiple queries with different bind args, see [`SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) and [`SQLiteStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html).

Comment: Oh ok, so I do not need to do anything else?

Comment: Is it not essentially calling the same thing for multiple queries already (my code) with just the argument pertaining to each word?

Comment: No, currently each call to `insert()` prepares a new statement (essentially a program in sqlite "bytecode") and runs it with the given args. With `SQLiteStatement`s you can run the same program with different args - useful if you use the same kind of queries over and over again.

Comment: Anyway you can show me an example?

Comment: The duplicate linked by Artoo Detoo has a simple example.